# Why menu icon color changes after running app [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please help

[image: menu icon while designing]

As the menu icon color is black here but when I run the app the menu icon color become white. I don't want it to be white. Please anyone assist.

[image: menu icon after running app]

Comment: you are designing your app in day lite mode  when you run the app  your device is in night mode I think so ..

Comment: @NiajMahmud No, my emulator is also in light mode

Comment: did you try any physical device ?

Comment: @NiajMahmud yes I tried, the menu icon is white in both cases, dark mode and light mode

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the colour values, because it seems to depend on your theme, as **Niaj Mahmud** said.

You should have something like this :

[image]

For example, you have

**colors.xml**

```xml
  <color name="colorPrimary">#FF808080</color>
```

--> this is the colour you see when designing.

**colors.xml (night)**

```xml
  <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFFF</color>
```

--> this is the colour you see when running the app.

You can practice [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-2%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme#0) if you want to exercise the theme changed on android (this is in Kotlin, but the same course exists in Java).

Comment: Mine have actually a single colors.xml. Here are some snapshots of my settings...... Colors.xml file https://ibb.co/nzsDyFw  themes.xml https://ibb.co/fHRPLq5  Values https://ibb.co/18mk80c

Comment: What is the content of the value-night/themes.xml ?

Comment: Same as the value for this theme.

Comment: Could you update your question and adding the content of the themes.xml and color.xml files as well as your layout files please ?

Comment: I don't know why but there isn't any edit option